# 10 chiens et chats veut-il dire 10 animaux en tout ou est-ce un sous-entendu de dix chiens et dix chats?

Tags: sens, expressions, choix-de-mot

Quand on dit "dix chiens et chats" veut-on dire qu'il y a en tout dix animaux et que ce sont des chiens et des chats, ou est-ce un sous-entendu qui veut désigner "dix chiens et dix chats"?

Et pour "une dizaine de chiens et de chats" alors?

Est-ce pareil pour tous les autres numéraux (deux, mille, une centaine, une douzaine, quatorze...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Dix chiens et chats*** équivaut à dix animaux

Ex. :

> [*Gers : propriétaire de **dix chiens et chats**, elle vit un calvaire pour trouver un logement
>
> Corinne Prignot accompagnée d’une partie de ses dix animaux de compagnie, **trois chiens et sept chats**.*](https://www.ladepeche.fr/2022/07/30/gers-proprietaire-de-dix-chiens-et-chats-elle-vit-un-calvaire-pour-trouver-un-logement-10458763.php)

> [***Dix chiens et chats** à adopter dans l’Aube
>
> Voici **cinq chiens et cinq chats** à adopter dans les différents refuges aubois.*](https://www.lest-eclair.fr/id100498/article/2019-10-13/vers-un-durcissement-de-la-loi-sur-les-abandons-danimaux)

Ce serait probablement la même chose avec *dix frères et sœurs* mais le contexte peut changer la donne. ***Dix frères et sœurs jumeaux*** sont probablement **vingt** de même que ***dix maris et femmes*** a beaucoup de chances de signifier **dix couples** soit là aussi **vingt** personnes.

Ex. :

> *Donc, dottore, les personnes qui ont participé à cette excursion étaient quarante. **Dix-huit maris et femmes**, ce qui fait **trente-six**, deux commères qui font souvent ces voyages ensemble et ça fait trente-huit et les jumeaux Laganà qui manquent pas une excursion, ils sont pas mariés et ils vivent dans la même maison.*
> Andrea Camillieri, *L'excursion à Tindari*, 2002

*Une dizaine de chiens et de chats* sera pour moi plus une dizaine d'animaux qu'une vingtaine. Sinon, j'aurais écrit quelque chose comme *une dizaine de chiens et autant de chats*.

Answer (score 2):

Propriétaire de dix chiens et chats peut signifier de six chiens et quatre chats.
Une dizaine de chiens ET de chats doit être considéré plutôt comme dix chiens et dix chats.

Le tout dépend du contexte à mon avis.

quatorze chiens et chats me paraît identique à la première formulation.
10 chiens et quatre chats.

Bonne question qui mérite une confirmation, mais à mon humble avis la réponse semble correcte.