# Question sur la fonction de l'adjectif numéral dans les coordinations

Tags: sens, coordination

On peut parfois lire sur les emballages de fruits et légumes le conseil suivant.

> Mangez au moins cinq fruits et légumes par jour

À mon avis il faut entendre par là

- « Mangez  chaque jour au moins de  cinq sortes de végétaux du type des fruits et des légumes ».

On ne peut pas comprendre « cinq fruits et cinq légumes » (cinq d'une seule sorte) puisque ce qui motive ce conseil c'est une nécessité plus ou moins reconnue d'assimiler  quotidiennement une  variété de vitamines aussi grande que possible. De plus, l'interprétation « cinq fruits différents et cinq légumes différents » a pour conséquence que l'on doit s'en tenir à une diète quasi - végétarienne pour laquelle chaque jour on doit prévoir un assortiment de dix végétaux.

Est-ce qu'une construction de ce type est justifiée ? C'est à dire trouve-t-on des combinaisons telles que les suivantes, auxquelles on donnerait le seul sens que je trouve plausible ?

- cinq arbres et bambous, six pantalons et chemises, quatre voitures et camions, cinq cachets et ampoules, etc.

(ex.:  Elle devait prendre chaque jour cinq cachets et ampoules.)

Si non, dans quelle mesure peut-on justifier « cinq fruits et légumes » en tant qu'exemple unique de cette construction ? En d'autres mots, si elle est unique, doit-on finalement considérer cette forme comme faisant partie du français correct ?

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/51262/10-chiens-et-chats-veut-il-dire-10-animaux-en-tout-ou-est-ce-un-sous-entendu-de/51265#51265

Comment: D'après vous, donc, c'est peu précis, on pourrait même dire indéfini, et, apparemment, vous n'en conseillez pas l'emploi.